# Get client machine's operating system name for both - tablet devices and PC

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website created in asp.net 3.5, c# 2008 - hosted on IIS 7. I want to check from which operating system the client is accessing the site, whether from browser of computer or from browser of tablet devices like ipad, dell streak, samsung galaxy etc or from the smart phone. Is it possible to know. I have tried out

```
Page.Request.Browser.Platform.ToString();
```

but accessing from android device browser I am getting it undefined.

I also have tried

```
Request.Browser.Capabilities["OS"].ToString();
```

but for android I am getting the OS name Linux !!

I want the exact name whether it is windows, Symbian, Android, iOS, MAC or Linux.

Comment: Perhaps this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5664612/141022

Comment: @Alex Is it really safe to provide your request information to any third party web?

Comment: Probably not (kinda), but in a way you're sending the user agent string to Google Analytics (I'm guessing). I'm guessing that these 3rd party services / libraries work via a (probably difficult to maintain) database of user agents to the equivelant break down of os's etc.

Comment: @Alex actually I think we should not be dependent on any third party web or service as there might be some security threats are there and also if that website gets down or something else happens there, our service also gets stopped. I need some concrete solution within my application that if any issue occurs I can control it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get it from the useragent

Comment: User agent for android shows both Linux and android. Like Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.2; en-us;....). How can I make sure that from which OS is it?

Comment: split the useragent with ";" and take the value from index 2

Comment: Nope, It will not give you an exact answer each time. For my Android device it is giving me "U".

Comment: How about calling it android if it contains "Android", even if it also contains "Linux"? Then, just call it "Linux" if it has linux but not android?